# Loading a static void C function via AndroidfromJNI another Package

Tags: java, reflection, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

I am trying some things out with JNI and by that I found the following problem:

If I want to use a native function in Java I load the needed lib, in which the needed function is stored, via

```
static{
     System.loadLibrary("lib");
}
```

and use

```
native private static int calculate(byte[] numberArray);
```

to declare the native method in the java file. During the program itself I can use this function to calculate something with:

```
int result = calculate(array);
```

This works only if I compiled the shared object with the header-file created by javah so that each function is named on c side as:

```
static void Java_com_packagename_File_calculate(const void* array, void* result){
    code[...]
}
```

If I delete the reference in the java code  ("native [...] calculate[...]")to this c function; is there any possibility to access / execute the still existing c-code via java (of course without editing the exisiting file ;-)) for example via reflections or inheritance? Or is there something possible like:

```
public class NewClass{

  public int nativeCheater(){
    System.loadLibrary("lib");
    native private static int Java_com_packagename_File_calculate;
  }        
}
```

It is important that I want to use a whole new class without any relations to the prior used package com.packagename.(File).

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create a new class with same package and class name and access the same native method. The new class can declare this method public.

An alternative is to use dynamic binding via Jni_OnLoad() and RegisterNatives(). This way, your native implementations may bind to any Java class, or even more than one.

But if you have access neither to the Java class nor to the native source, you can always create your own native method, in your own class, and inside *your* C explicitly call the original:

```
static void Java_com_mypackagename_File_calculate(const void* array, void* result) {     
  Java_com_packagename_File_calculate(array, result);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried to add a new class via URLClassLoader but I wasn't able to use the new Class. If I use (after loading) Class.forName("com.package.File").getDeclaredMethods() I receive an array containing the methods of the old file. Could you maybe provide a codesample?

Comment: I don't think Android JVMs allow loading two classes with the same full names twice. My answer implied that you use a new class *instead* of the original. `RegisterNatives()` approach will work, but this requires access to native code. On the other hand, if you have access neither to the Java class nor to the native source, I added the third approach for you.